# Different effects with different screens sizes

Tags: javascript, onclick, responsiveness

I have a Javascript that already works but I would like to have a different effect on my mobile version. How do I do that? Here is my try at it so far.

```
if (screen.width > 736) { 

}
else {
   var mouseX;
   var mouseY;
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
      mouseX = e.pageX; 
      mouseY = e.pageY;
   });  
   $(".kunden-item").on('click', function(event){
       $("#divId").show().css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
   });
   $(".kunden-item").mouseout(function(){
        $('#divId').fadeOut('middle');
   });
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put all your code block inside of dom ready like that

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
if (screen.width > 736) { 

}
else {
      var mouseX;
      var mouseY;
      mouseX = e.pageX; 
      mouseY = e.pageY;
      $(".kunden-item").on('click', function(event){
       $("#divId").show().css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
     });
     $(".kunden-item").mouseout(function(){
         $('#divId').fadeOut('middle');
     });
   }
});
```